# S=0 in URL's of ExpressionEngine site

Tags: url

`S=0` is randomly appearing in URL's of an ExpressionEngine site that is being developed. Has anyone encountered this before? If so, what was the issue?

Example of url: `example.com/S=0/search/results/`

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you have "User Session Type" set to "Cookies only". ([Docs.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/security_settings.html#user-session-type))

Comment: `Cookies only` can cause issues with other modules such as Cartthrob. Setting `User Session Type` to `Cookies & session ID` fixes the above URL issue and also allows other modules to use sessions.